# вывод промежуточных данных в строку таблицы c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms, aspx

Есть веб-форма, на которой существует несколько выпадающих списков и некая таблица с заполненными данными. 
[image: пример выгрузки запроса из бд, внимание на поле pocket_num]
поле Pocket_num соответствует выбору выпадающего списка, если список не выбран, то показывает все значения.
Моя задача:на вебформе, по окончанию всех записей одного кармана (т.е. поле pocket_num) вывести промежуточную строчку, в которой он посчитает мне количество строк с полем pocket_num равным одному значению. Т.е. для значения 1, 3 и так далее. Таблица реализована через создание отдельно шапки и тела таблицы.
TableRow и TableCell соответственно

Сейчас я веду подсчет только в том случае, когда выпадающий список, который отвечает за поле Pocket_num выбран.

вот как я это реализовал и вывел в label на aspx форме.

```
 // кол-во труб
        int CountPipes = 0;
        String CountPipesSQL = "select count(*) " + MainQueryPart2;

        cmd.CommandText = CountPipesSQL;
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        OleDbDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (Reader.Read())
        {
            CountPipes = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["count(*)"]);
            CountOfPipes.Text = "Сейчас в кармане находится: " + CountPipes.ToString() + " труб";
        }

        Reader.Dispose();
        Reader.Close();
```

Comment: [Display SubTotal and Grand Total in ASP.Net GridView](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-SubTotal-and-Grand-Total-in-ASPNet-GridView.aspx)?

Comment: @tym32167 а можно ли это реализовать через отдельное построение шапки и тело таблицы, с помощью создания tableRow и tableCell, потому что у меня реализовано так

Comment: не попробуете - не узнаете